# Pass value and not id from dropdown list

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, listbox, dropdown

How can I pass the exact text from a dropdown list, and not its value.
I'm using CodeIgniter,

```
$tableNames = array_column($tableData, 'TABLE_NAME');
        asort($tableNames);
        echo form_open('index.php/TableController');
        echo form_dropdown('TABLE_NAME', $tableNames);
        echo "<br><br>";
        echo form_submit("submit1", "Table");
        echo form_close();
```

This results passing the id of the selected item, not it's text.
I don't want to pass the whole array and select the text again with the id, I just want to pass the text to my Controller.

Comment: don't set a value. default browser behavior is to send the option text if  there's no value. e.g. `<option>Foo</option>` sends `Foo`, while `<option value="bar">Foo</option>` would send `bar`. that or just set the text into the value: `<option value="Foo">Foo</option>`. And note that mentioning `id` is confusing. DOM `id` fields are NOT submitted with a form.

Comment: not sure what you are asking, but in a typical dropdown list <select...><option value="...value1...This value get send">And This is display to user</option><option value="...value2...">And so on...</option></select>

Comment: Thank for the answers, its clear that I can do it in plain html, but is it available with CodeIgniter framework? I did not find the answer in its documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the magic:

```
$tableNames = array_combine($tableNames, $tableNames);
```

I got the associative array with keys and values the same, so if I pass it to the form dropdown, both the option value and the text will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter 3.0.4 **form_dropdown(name, options)**

```
$options = array(
   'small'         => 'Small Shirt',
   'med'           => 'Medium Shirt',
   'large'         => 'Large Shirt',
   'xlarge'        => 'Extra Large Shirt',
);

echo form_dropdown('shirts', $options);
```

Result:

```
<select name="shirts">
  <option value="small">Small Shirt</option>
  <option value="med">Medium  Shirt</option>
  <option value="large">Large Shirt</option>
  <option value="xlarge">Extra Large Shirt</option>
</select>
```

Ref: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

Your question is bit unclear. But will give it ago Pass your array items from controller to view is better.

You can try this

File name: Test.php

```
<?php

class Test extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {

        $data['records'] = array(

            array(
                'id' => 2135,
                'value' => 'John',
            ),

            array(
            'id' => 3245,
            'value' => 'Sally',
            ),

            array(
                'id' => 5342,
                'value' => 'Jane',

            ),
            array(
                'id' => 5623,
                'value' => 'Peter',
            )

        );

        $this->load->view('test', $data);
    }

    public function submit_test() {
      var_dump($this->input->post('test'));
      exit;
    }
}
```

On Your view

```
<?php

echo form_open_multipart('index.php/test/submit_test');

$array_items = array_column($records, 'value', 'id');

$s = array(
        'class'=> 'form-control'
);

echo form_dropdown('test', $array_items, '', $s);

echo form_submit("submit", "Table");

echo form_close();

?>
```

Produces

[image]